# How to solve for a specific gradient in an implicit relationship, when no points are known?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

### The problem

Consider the following relation:
$$x^2-3xy+y^2=7$$

I'm struggling with what is essentially the following task:

> Find all coordinates of all points where the gradient of the tangent of the curve is ${2\over3}$.

Using implicit differentiation, I arrive at the following derivative of $y$ wrt $x$:
$${\text dy\over\text dx}=\frac{3y-2x}{2y-3x}$$

This is somewhat of a mindbender for me, since it looks like the derivative itself depends on both $x$ and $y$. How can this be? How does one work with this?

Even more daunting is the task of solving $\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}=\frac{2}{3}$. The equation cannot be solved as we have a single, two-variable equation: $$2(2y-3x)=3(3y-2x)$$
Sadder yet is that by my logic, there is an infinite number of solutions ($xy$ pairs) that satisfy this. Unfortunately, graphing this relation gives the solution set $(x,0)$ where $x\inℝ$.

The correct answer is $(\sqrt7,0)\cup(-\sqrt7,0)$.

### My questions

1. How do I work with a derivative which depends on both $x$ and $y$, and conceptually, how is that even possible?
2. Why is it that graphing the solutions of $2(2y-3x)=3(3y-2x)$ did not work and gave erroneous solutions?
3. How is the answer $(\sqrt7,0)\cup(-\sqrt7,0)$ obtained?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You've shown that if the derivative is $2/3$ then the points must lie on the given line. But you have to intersect this line with the original curve in order to find any valid solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** As per comment everywhere where you read ellipse you should read hyperbola.

In your case the curve is an ellipse. If you go to a value $x$, what is the derivative of the function? Well, it is not clearly defined. First you need to find $y$. You can have 0, 1, or 2 $y$ values corresponding to a single $x$. So where do you calculate the derivative? You need to choose $y$ to be on the ellipsis.
Think for example that you have a circle of radius $1$, centered at the origin. And you want to calculate the derivative at $x=0.5$. You notice that you have two intersections. At $y=\sqrt 3/2$ you have a negative derivative, but at $y=-\sqrt 3/2$ the derivative is positive.

So you have an equation for the derivative that involve $x$ and $y$. But you also know that $(x,y)$ is on the given curve. That's the second equation.

What you need to do is to write $y(x)$ from the derivative equation, plug it into the equation for the curve, find $x$, then find $y(x)$.

Let me know how these steps work for you.

Comment: I believe the curve is a hyperbola since $x^2-3xy+y^2 = (x-\frac{3}{2}y)^2-\frac{5}{4}y^{2}$

Comment: Or as is simpler to see: solving for $y$ in $x^2-3xy+y^{2}=7$ gives $y = \frac{1}{2}(3x\pm\sqrt{5x^{2}+28})$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski OOps. I misread the sign. It is indeed a hyperbola. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! That the points lie on the curve was the missing piece of info that indeed collapsed the possible solutions into just two. I totally forgot that I could use the first relation as the second equation in a system. Thanks a lot for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

When you differentiated you obtained the derivative for any of the curves $$x^{2}-3xy+y^{2}=c. \tag{1}$$
Too see that these curves are different you can let $c=0$ then $(0,0)$ is on the curve, but if $c=1$ then $(0,0)$ is not a point on the curve, more generally $(\sqrt{c},0)$ is unique on each curve in $(1)$.

Simplifying $2(2y-3x)=3(3y-2x)$ you will obtain $y=0$ and pluggin that into $(1)$ gives
$$x^{2}=\sqrt{c}$$
which as you can see has a solution for any $c\geq 0$. Here you can see how the solutions to your problem came about, but more importantly the family of hyperbels in $(1)$ where $c\geq 0$ all have the slope $\frac{2}{3}$ at two points. Since there are infinitley many choices of $c$ and each curve in the family is different, there must be an infinite number of points on the derivative to account for every $c$ and therefore it is a curve.